# Get record by id

Tags: php, html, mysql

### Here is my code:

```
case 'records': $this-> get_records ($callParams[1]); 

private function get_records($id)
{
$result = get_records_info ($id) ;
if(count($result) > 0)
$this->response($this->text/html($result), 200);
else        
$this->response('',204);
}

function get_records_info (){
$result = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM `records` ") 
or die(mysql_error());
while($records = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {  
echo "<div>" .$records['records_name']. "</div>";
echo "<div>info:"  .$records['w']. $records['l']. $records['d']. $records['k']."</div>";
echo "<div>info2:".$records['info2']."</div>";  
   }

}
```

---

Here is what I'm trying to do:

When you click on records is goes to `domain.com/record/id` and only displays the record of that id.

Here is what is happening:
I got it to work but I'm getting all the records in the database.

Comment: *sidenote:* stop using deprecated `mysql_*` functions. use [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead. Here is a good [tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ) for PDO.

Comment: given that your get_records_info()  doesn't RETURN anything, `$result` will never be set with anything but a null. And since your query doesn't have a `where` clause, you'll always get the "all the records".

Comment: Is the tab/space key note working? Indent the code

Answer (score 0):

Your result is currently:

```
mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM `records` ")
```

This is going to grab all the records regardless. What you want is something like this:

```
mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM `records` WHERE `id` = '$id' ")
```

**`$id`** being the supplied id to fetch the record for.

**Note:** As stated in the comments, stay away from `mysql_*` functions as it is depreciated. Look into PDO or MySQLi :)

Comment: ... also use prepared statements to avoid SQL injection

Answer (score 0):

try this.... You are passing the id in function but not using thats why it is showing you all recrods, pass id in function function get_records_info ($id) then in query .

```
<?php

//case 'records': $this-> get_records ($callParams[1]);
case 'records': $this-> get_records ($id); //just pass the id of the user here

private function get_records($id)
{
$result = get_records_info ($id) ;
if(count($result) > 0)
$this->response($this->text/html($result), 200);
else
$this->response('',204);
}

function get_records_info ($id){
$result = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM `records` where `id` = ' ".$id." ' ")
or die(mysql_error());
while($records = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
echo "<div>" .$records['records_name']. "</div>";
echo "<div>info:"  .$records['w']. $records['l']. $records['d']. $records['k']."</div>";
echo "<div>info2:".$records['info2']."</div>";
   }

}

?>
```

Comment: so i tried this -- >  $result = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM `records` where `id` = ' ".$id." ' ") and its not working at all now. Im not receiving any records

Comment: thanks for the help. Im very new to MYSQL. Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: still at it.. Im trying the suggestions but not working. could be something else. Strange i can get the data by ID as JSON but not HTML

Comment: i have edited the answer just pass the id of user in this function ->
case 'records': $this-> get_records ($id);

Comment: still not working... i'll figure something else out, cant keep at this. Been on this for 5 days. Thanks for all the help.